# Linq/lambda question about .Select (newby learning 3.0)

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, lambda

I am playing with the new stuff of C#3.0 and I have this code (mostly taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)) but I can only get true,false,true... and not the real value :

```
        int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };

        var oddNumbers = numbers.Select(n => n % 2 == 1);

        Console.WriteLine("Numbers < 5:");
        foreach (var x in oddNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
```

How can I fix that to show the list of integer?

Comment: Seems n % 2 == 1 has nothing to do with Numbers < 5?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change your "Select" to a "Where"

```
    int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };

    var oddNumbers = numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 1);

    Console.WriteLine("Odd Number:");
    foreach (var x in oddNumbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

The "Select" method is creating a new list of the lambda result for each element (true/false).  The "Where" method is filtering based on the lambda.

In C#, you could also use this syntax, which you may find clearer:

```
        var oddNumbers = from n in numbers
                         where n % 2 == 1
                         select n;
```

which the compiler translates to:

```
var oddNumbers = numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 1).Select(n => n);
```

Comment: It does select data.  It's selecting the result of your lambda - which is a boolean value.

Comment: Just to let you know that var oddNumbers = numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 1).Select(n); doesn't work.

Comment: I see what you mean, you were referring to my attempted compiler translation example.  I fixed that - but I didn't mean for you to use that.  Just the first answer that I gave (which compiled).
var oddNumbers = numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 1);

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> numbers.Select(n => n % 2 == 1);
> ```

Change this to

```
numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 1);
```

What select does is "convert" one thing to another. So in this case, it's "Converting" n to "n % 2 == 1" (which is a boolean) - hence you get all the true and falses.

It's usually used for getting properties on things. For example if you had a list of `Person` objects, and you wanted to get their names, you'd do

```
var listOfNames = listOfPeople.Select( p => p.Name );
```

You can think of this like so:

- Convert the list of people into a list of strings, using the following method: ( p => p.Name)

To "select" (in the "filtering" sense of the word) a subset of a collection, you need to use Where.

Thanks Microsoft for the terrible naming

Comment: Yeah, same as SQL, but different to every other programming language (ruby, lisp, python, etc, etc) which use map for 'select' and select for 'where'

Comment: ... and in F#, "map" is "Select", and "filter" is "Where". Very nice IMHO.